# Semi-transparent eraser brush on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to write a semi-transparent eraser brush into an app I'm developing but have found two problems crop up depending on how it is implemented.  Hopefully there is a workaround I can get pointed at.

Code samples are in mono droid / xamarin

So, pretty typically I have a setup which draws paths on to a drawing canvas. the `OnDraw` method of my view draws its basic bitmap and then my path on top of that.

```
    // Canvas is set up elsewhere
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
    DrawCanvas.SetBitmap(canvasBitmap);


    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        // Draw the saved canvas bitmap
        canvas.DrawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

        // On top of that draw the current path
        canvas.DrawPath(DrawPath, DrawPaint);
    }



    public bool OnTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev)
    {
        float touchX = ev.GetX();
        float touchY = ev.GetY();


        switch (ev.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:

                if (Editable)
                {
                    // I've removed a bunch of code here but it basically
                    // moves the path start to the touch point and sets
                    // up the brush to start erasing. It does set the
                    // porterduff mode to dstOur
                    DrawPaint.SetMaskFilter(null);
                    DrawPaint.SetXfermode( new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DstOut));

                    DrawPath.MoveTo(touchX, touchY);

                } else { return false;  }
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Move:

                // Just draws a line to the new touch coordinates
                DrawPath.LineTo(touchX, touchY);

                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:

                // saves some data about the path and draws to the drawing canvas.
                DrawCanvas.DrawPath(DrawPath, DrawPaint);

                // Recycle it
                DrawPath.Reset();

                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

So there are two ways to draw the eraser line while it is being drawn.  The first is to draw on to the drawing canvas (which writes to the `canvasBitmap`) and the second is to draw directly on the `canvas` provided by `OnDraw`.

My problems are as follows:

If I draw on to the `DrawCanvas` I get a stacking effect where the erased line gets progressively more and more transparent.  This is kind of understandable because during each `OnDraw` loop the eraser path is being baked down into the `canvasBitmap`.

If I draw directly on to the `canvas` provided by `OnDraw` I get the "[black line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094845/implementing-an-eraser-in-an-android-drawing-app-black-trail-and-then-transpar?rq=1)" problem which also makes some sense as it is erasing on to nothing.  When the path is drawn on to the `canvasBitmap` in the `Up` event then everything looks right and there's a nice semi-transparent eraser line.

Ideally there is a different solution of which I am not aware for the "[black line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094845/implementing-an-eraser-in-an-android-drawing-app-black-trail-and-then-transpar?rq=1)" problem but I've not been able to find anything.  I've also tried thinking of ways to cache the `canvasBitmap` and while a draw event is in progress use that rather than the active copy being drawn to by the `Move` events.

Does anyone have something I could take a look at which might suggest a solution?  Java is fine as it's easy to port to c#.

Many thanks in advance!
Nigel

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of someone with more experience/smarts than me having a suggestion, I got around it in the follow horrible way.  It might still be helpful for someone else while I continue to find a smarter way to do it.

When the `Down` event happens I grab a clean copy of the bitmap into a temporary variable. On each `OnDraw` event I readraw that clean bitmap and then draw the erase path on top of that.

The horrible bit is that each `OnDraw` event has a bitmap copy method in it to ensure that a doubling of the erase path doesn't happen.

```
OnDraw( Canvas canvas )
{
            tempBitmap.Recycle();
            tempBitmap = _drawingBitmap.Copy(_drawingBitmap.GetConfig(), true);

            DrawCanvas.DrawColor(Color.Transparent, PorterDuff.Mode.Clear);
            DrawCanvas.DrawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, DrawPaint));
            DrawCanvas.DrawPath(DrawPath, DrawPaint);
}
```

The bitmap recycling is pretty critical obviously.  On the `.Up` event in the touch listener it recycles again and then nulls the variable.

Not pretty, but it works.

Any better ideas much appreciated!