# How to add an eraser in custom paint?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, custom-painting

I'm currently building a painting app with custom paint and every works great, I have a button to clear everything has been painted on the screen, but I'm looking for a normal eraser that can clear any specific line have been drawn not all of them at once how can this be done with custom paint, here is an example code of a painting app near to what I'm working on

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';

class Draw extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawState createState() => _DrawState();
}

class _DrawState extends State<Draw> {
  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;
  Color pickerColor = Colors.black;
  double strokeWidth = 3.0;
  List<DrawingPoints> points = List();
  bool showBottomList = false;
  double opacity = 1.0;
  StrokeCap strokeCap = (Platform.isAndroid) ? StrokeCap.butt : StrokeCap.round;
  SelectedMode selectedMode = SelectedMode.StrokeWidth;
  List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.amber,
    Colors.black
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                color: Colors.greenAccent),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.album),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (selectedMode == SelectedMode.StrokeWidth)
                                showBottomList = !showBottomList;
                              selectedMode = SelectedMode.StrokeWidth;
                            });
                          }),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.opacity),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (selectedMode == SelectedMode.Opacity)
                                showBottomList = !showBottomList;
                              selectedMode = SelectedMode.Opacity;
                            });
                          }),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.color_lens),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (selectedMode == SelectedMode.Color)
                                showBottomList = !showBottomList;
                              selectedMode = SelectedMode.Color;
                            });
                          }),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              showBottomList = false;
                              points.clear();
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    child: (selectedMode == SelectedMode.Color)
                        ? Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: getColorList(),
                          )
                        : Slider(
                            value: (selectedMode == SelectedMode.StrokeWidth)
                                ? strokeWidth
                                : opacity,
                            max: (selectedMode == SelectedMode.StrokeWidth)
                                ? 50.0
                                : 1.0,
                            min: 0.0,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (selectedMode == SelectedMode.StrokeWidth)
                                  strokeWidth = val;
                                else
                                  opacity = val;
                              });
                            }),
                    visible: showBottomList,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          setState(() {
            RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
            points.add(DrawingPoints(
                points: renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition),
                paint: Paint()
                  ..strokeCap = strokeCap
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
          });
        },
        onPanStart: (details) {
          setState(() {
            RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
            points.add(DrawingPoints(
                points: renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition),
                paint: Paint()
                  ..strokeCap = strokeCap
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
          });
        },
        onPanEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            points.add(null);
          });
        },
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size.infinite,
          painter: DrawingPainter(
            pointsList: points,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getColorList() {
    List<Widget> listWidget = List();
    for (Color color in colors) {
      listWidget.add(colorCircle(color));
    }
    Widget colorPicker = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Pick a color!'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ColorPicker(
                pickerColor: pickerColor,
                onColorChanged: (color) {
                  pickerColor = color;
                },
                enableLabel: true,
                pickerAreaHeightPercent: 0.8,
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('Save'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => selectedColor = pickerColor);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
          height: 36,
          width: 36,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
    listWidget.add(colorPicker);
    return listWidget;
  }

  Widget colorCircle(Color color) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedColor = color;
        });
      },
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
          height: 36,
          width: 36,
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  DrawingPainter({this.pointsList});
  List<DrawingPoints> pointsList;
  List<Offset> offsetPoints = List();
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(pointsList[i].points, pointsList[i + 1].points,
            pointsList[i].paint);
      } else if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] == null) {
        offsetPoints.clear();
        offsetPoints.add(pointsList[i].points);
        offsetPoints.add(Offset(
            pointsList[i].points.dx + 0.1, pointsList[i].points.dy + 0.1));
        canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, offsetPoints, pointsList[i].paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawingPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

class DrawingPoints {
  Paint paint;
  Offset points;
  DrawingPoints({this.points, this.paint});
}

enum SelectedMode { StrokeWidth, Opacity, Color }
```

Comment: this answer may help you.
[Adding an eraser to custom painter in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626727/how-to-erase-clip-from-canvas-custompaint)

Comment: check out this answer to a [similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61844527)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, what I did was changing the brush color to the background color, you can change the `strokeWidth` too, you will draw more strokes but it will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code:

```
showBottomList = false;
```